# Cannot install artoolkit 6

Tags: artoolkit

While trying to install artoolkit 6 on my ubuntu I get multiple errors.
First I tried installing artoolkit6-dev_6.0.2_amd64.deb which gave an error complaining not installed package artoolkit6-lib then I tried below.

```
sudo dpkg -i artoolkit6-lib_6.0.2_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package artoolkit6-lib.
(Reading database ... 286474 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack artoolkit6-lib_6.0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking artoolkit6-lib (6.0.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of artoolkit6-lib:
 artoolkit6-lib depends on libgoogle-glog0v5; however:
  Package libgoogle-glog0v5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package artoolkit6-lib (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 artoolkit6-lib
```

But I cannot find libgoogle0v5 anywhere to install.
Where can I find this package ?

My machine info:

```
Linux xxxxx-ThinkPad-T410 3.19.0-84-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 24 15:46:19 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: try to complete the installation with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f` it will be installed automatically and the installation of artoolkit will be finished

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same behavior ...

It seems that libgoogle-glog0v5 is a logger at application level.
I found a DL link here:
https://pkgs.org/download/libgoogle-glog0v5

Additionally I had to install the libgflags2v5 package, because the .deb   file for libgoogle was missing that dependency.
https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libgflags2v5

Installation Process:

1. libgflags2v5
   The installation via Ubuntu softwarecenter failed, but worked in a 
   terminal window:

   `sudo dpkg -i libgflags2v5_2.1.2-4_amd64.deb`
2. libgoogle-glog0v5

   `sudo - libgoogle-glog0v5_0.3.4-0.1_amd64.deb`
3. artoolkit6-lib

   `sudo dpkg -i artoolkit6-lib_6.0.2_amd64.deb`
4. artoolkit6-dev

   `sudo dpkg -i artoolkit6-dev_6.0.2_amd64.deb`
5. for installing the examples folder of ARToolkit 6 I also had to install

   `sudo dpkg -i libgflags2v5_2.1.2-4_amd64.deb`

... and some others more. just follow the names of the missing dependency packages and install them.

```
sudo apt-get install libsndio6.1  

sudo apt-get install x11proto-video-dev
```

libsdl2-2.0-0: Simple DirectMedia Layer:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0  

sudo dpkg -i libsdl2-dev.deb

sudo dpkg -i artoolkit6-examples_6.0.2_amd64
```

finally the installation of the artoolkit6 samples is finished.

Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

I hope this helps!